# Parts of webpage only displaying halfscreen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I'm not sure whats happening here. I thought this was working fine before and now when I look at it the news is displaying fine...but on iphone and maybe any mobile its only filling half the screen.

I could try to use the inspector on chrome to fix it but the site is filling the screen on desktop but still only half on the actual device. Any idea what might be the issue? I messed around with the media queries but its not helping.

The news section is working fine but the rest are only filling half the screen.

[greenpointpictures.com](http://greenpointpictures.com)

Comment: Have you set your viewport in meta tag right?